# Any way to view doc for c API in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I suddenly found Xcode have very poo support for view the C API docs.

Suppose if you want to find the definition for `fopen`, you can't find any meaningful info for this function expected the declare.

So any workaround for this?

---

Edit according to Mark Szymczyk's  suggestion.

My problem is when I `Option` click the function, it just show this function is declare in `stdio.h`, no more explanation to this function like other cocoa APIs.

And when I search in the  documentation viewer, it shows something like this, this will cost a little time to figure out it.

[image]

Comment: When I type **fopen** in the search bar in Xcode 7's documentation viewer, I get the man page for fopen. Is your problem that the man page doesn't provide enough information about fopen? If not, update your question with what you expect to find and what your are finding when you search the documentation in Xcode.

Comment: What happens when you click the link for Mac OS X Manual Page For fopen in your screenshot? It shows the man page for me. Each of those Mac OS X Manual Page listings in your screenshot are clickable links to man pages.

Comment: Also the man page, just feel waste a little time compared to view Cocoa API.@MarkSzymczyk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for you with Xcode. Apple's top priority with Xcode is developers of apps on Apple's platforms using Apple's technologies. That priority also applies to documentation. For standard C language APIs, Apple supplies man pages. If that is not good enough, you're out of luck.

A possible solution is to use [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash), a documentation viewer app. If you can find a comprehensive documentation set for the C language APIs, you could import it into Dash and read it from there.